# Help understanding current sense application note to inject feedback into buck converter

Tags: circuit-analysis, buck, current-limiting, constant-current

I am trying to understand [this application note](https://www.maximintegrated.com/en/design/reference-design-center/ref-circuits/478.html) using [MAX4173H](https://datasheets.maximintegrated.com/en/ds/MAX4173-MAX4173T.pdf) to inject feedback into a [MAX1692](https://datasheets.maximintegrated.com/en/ds/MAX1692.pdf) step-down converter.

How to they determine the precise point at which the current limit will kick in, is it the point at which the forward voltage of D1 starts to be exceeded? Does R1 and R4 form a voltage adder?

What i think i understand so far.

1. The feedback voltage of the converter is 1.213-1.285v
2. When there is 0.3A of output the current sense amplifier will output a voltage of 0.06 x 100 x 0.3 = 1.8V
3. The forward voltage of the diode D1 is 1v

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The datasheet for the MAX4173H states the formula for Vout (page 7):

Vout = Gain * Rsense * Iload.

It also states Gain = 100 for the "H" device.

For the values given in the application note (0.06 Ohm and 300mA) that makes 1.8V.

The MAX1692 will regulate towards 1.25V on it's feedback pin. If current exceeds the maximum allowed the MAX4173H will start pulling the MAX1692's feedback pin up, prompting it to lower it's output voltage.

They apparantly took 1.8 - 1.25= 0.55V as the voltage drop for the diode.

At the moment the current limit kicks in, the feedback pin is already at 1.25V due to normal regulation so hardly any current will flow trough R4, so one can ignore it's voltage drop.